# Get all chars not in string python

Tags: python

I'm trying to randomly insert characters into a string and I want to be able to strip them out later, so I have to use characters that are not already in the string. I want to use as many characters as possible.  How can I get a list of all the characters that are not in the string? I am using Python 2.

Comment: There are [a lot of characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) which are not in the string.  Do you really want all of them?

Comment: use `set`s. (e.g. : `set('some letters') - set('other letters')`)

Comment: ASCII characters? Use [`string.ascii_letters`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters) and [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big assumption I'm making here is that you're working with an ASCII string.

Valid characters have integer values between 0 and 255. As such, the following will generate a complete set of all of the valid characters:

```
all_chars = set(chr(i) for i in range(256))
```

You can then get the set of characters in your string. That's as easy as running `set(mystring)`.

The difference between those is the subset of what's in `all_chars`, but not in your string:

```
unused_chars = all_chars - set(mystring)
```

So putting that all together:

```
def get_unused_chars(mystring):
    # Generate the list of every valid ASCII character
    all_chars = set(chr(i) for i in range(256))

    # Determine which characters are unused
    unused_chars = all_chars - set(mystring)

    return unused_chars
```

Comment: Do you know how I could only use characters that don't start with a backslash?

Comment: use string.printable (from https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.printable ). You can also use other characters sets if you don't want to include the whitespace characters.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have a set of all possible characters:

```
>>> characters = set('ABCabc')
```

then it is as simple as

```
>>> my_str = "abbaAC"
>>> not_in_string = characters - set(my_str)
>>> not_in_string
set(['c', 'B'])
```

Answer (score 2):

What is a "letter"?

Assuming ascii:

```
set(string.ascii_letters) - set(yourstring)
```

otherwise, define your alphabet appropriately first, then use

```
set(youralphabet) - set(yourstring)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to achieve this:

```
>>> not_in = 'abcde'                                                                                                       
>>> other_string = 'remove char in'                                                                                        

>>> char_not_in = "".join([c for c in other_string if not c in not_in])                                                    
>>> print(char_not_in)
'rmov hr in'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick (given that you want your output string to have a specific size):

```py
from string import letters
from random import choice


def random_letters(not_in, size=1):
    i = 1
    out = []
    while(i <= size):
        char = choice(letters)
        if char.lower() not in not_in:
            out.append(char)
            i += 1
    return ''.join(c for c in out)

print(random_letters('abc', 3))
```

this outputs a random string without a, b or c of size 3.